# Why does opencv save the same image?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to capture an image from a camera and save it. I'll be doing some computations in between but for the purposes of the question I'm not. (ie the line below `doStuff()` is commented)

The problem is that I'm always saving the same image and I don't understand why. It seems as I'm not flushing a memory buffer or something similar?

I tried the example [from the docs](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html#capture-video-from-camera) and it worked fine. Also, in the actual implementation `getFrame` is defined in a different file and imported but I don't think this should matter.

Any help appreciated

```
import cv2
import time, datetime

def getFrame(cap, fn='image'):
    timeString = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%H_%M_%S_%Y_%m_%d')
    readSuccess, frame = cap.read()
    pn = os.getcwd() + '/Images/'
    if readSuccess:
        cv2.imwrite(pn+fn+'_'+timeString+'.png', frame)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
for ii in range(10):
    doStuff() # this doesn't really matter, I'm testing it with this line commented
    getFrame(cap) # <- this always saves the same image
```

**EDIT**

After a bit more testing:

It isn't actually capturing the same image but it seems to be the *next* image. By next I mean that if you consider this to be a live stream it simply moves on to the next image that would've been captured, to make it clearer:

If it has a 10 image buffer for example, once a `.read` is run it captures 10 images closely spaced. So when I do the next `.read` command it simply returns the previously captured image and adds one to the buffer. I'm doing a bit of guess work here but I think this is what is happening. This would explain why the example from the docs above works fine, and this all makes sense with regards to things you would want in case of a live stream, but not in my case.

Has anyone seen this behaviour before? A workaround?

**EDIT2**

I inserted the following code:

```
for ii in range(10):
    cap.grab()
```

right after the line `def getFrame(cap, fn='image'):` and thinks work, however I'm dubmstruck at this and still don't quite understand it. I'm hoping someone has (a) a better solution and (b) maybe an actual explanation rather than my guesstimates.

Thank you!

Comment: Are _all_ of the images the same if you capture over a long period of time (many seconds) or if you add a long pause between captures? It may just be that the camera has not yet had time to take another frame in the time that you can save 10 images to file.

Comment: they are all the same... even if I just do it manually, ie I define `getFrame` and then just type `getFrame(cap)` in a terminal and wait to see the image and then do it again it's the same. Does this make sense?

Comment: ok I tried again but now I'm printing the frame, it seems to me that instead of capturing the current frame there is some sort of buffer, because the faster I do the `getFrame(cap)` the more accurate it is. This is the craziest behaviour I've ever seen. Also, it is very strange that the example from the docs I've listed works fine, **in real time**

Comment: This is likely to be a bug, since [read](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-read) is supposed to `grab` already (doc's the same for opencv 2.4.9)

Comment: I think it is grabbing but there is a buffer, so it grabs the next image in the buffer and a "fresh" image is loaded at the end of the queue. No idea if this is a bug or not...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like my guestimating was correct, I found this [link](http://answers.opencv.org/question/29957/highguivideocapture-buffer-introducing-lag/) with this [answer](http://answers.opencv.org/question/29957/highguivideocapture-buffer-introducing-lag/?answer=31513#post-id-31513) where the same problem was experienced and a similar "hack" was used as suggested in my **EDIT2**.

If I have time I'll improve the answer, I think that reading images constantly and only keeping the ones that I want is probably a better solution, which I'll write up if I have time.